# How is Windows 11 Apache php 8 Apache manual setup different from the php 7 on windows 10

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, php, mysql

I have read previous post on the setup of Apache php MySQL manual installation and the all seems to follow the same steps. Please what would be the constant k in all the different different versions and what we should look out for to update to the latest version we are want to install. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the problem? Questions must specify a problem and not ask general questions.